# Locking issue with LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler and aync/await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I'm struggling to understand what's happening in this simple program.

In the example below I have a task factory that uses the  LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler from ParallelExtensionsExtras with maxDegreeOfParallelism set to 2.

I then start 2 tasks that each call an async method (e.g. an async Http request), then gets the awaiter and the result of the completed task.

The problem seem to be that `Task.Delay(2000)` never completes. If I set maxDegreeOfParallelism to 3 (or greater) it completes. But with maxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 (or less) my guess is that there is no thread available to complete the task. Why is that?

It seems to be related to async/await since if I remove it and simply do `Task.Delay(2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in `DoWork` it works perfectly. Does async/await somehow use the parent task's task scheduler, or how is it connected?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Schedulers;

namespace LimitedConcurrency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TaskSchedulerTest();
            test.Run();
        }
    }

    class TaskSchedulerTest
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2);
            var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(id => taskFactory.StartNew(() => DoWork(id)));
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private void DoWork(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting Work {id}");
            HttpClientGetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished Work {id}");
        }

        async Task HttpClientGetAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can safely assume that "LimitedConcurrency" means what it says.  A flexible not-limited task scheduler deals with deadlock bugs in a constructive way, it does raise the concurrency level beyond the optimum.  Like ThreadPool and Task do.  Use Debug > Windows > Threads to see what is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`await` by default captures the current context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and uses that to resume the `async` method. This context is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

In this case, `await` is capturing the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` used to execute `DoWork`. So, after starting the `Task.Delay` both times, both of those threads are blocked (due to the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`). When the `Task.Delay` completes, the `await` schedules the remainder of the `HttpClientGetAsync` method to its context. However, the context will not run it since it already has 2 threads.

So you end up with threads blocked in the context until their `async` methods complete, but the `async` methods cannot complete until there is a free thread in the context; thus a deadlock. Very similar to the [standard "don't block on async code" style of deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), just with *n* threads instead of one.

Clarifications:

> The problem seem to be that Task.Delay(2000) never completes.

`Task.Delay` is completing, but the `await` cannot continue executing the `async` method.

> If I set maxDegreeOfParallelism to 3 (or greater) it completes. But with maxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 (or less) my guess is that there is no thread available to complete the task. Why is that?

There are plenty of threads available. But the `LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler` only allows 2 threads at a time to run in its context.

> It seems to be related to async/await since if I remove it and simply do Task.Delay(2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult() in DoWork it works perfectly.

Yes; it's the `await` that is capturing the context. `Task.Delay` does not capture a context internally, so it can complete without needing to enter the `LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler`.

Solution:

Task schedulers in general do not work very well with asynchronous code. This is because task schedulers were designed for Parallel Tasks rather than asynchronous tasks. So they only apply when code is *running* (or blocked). In this case, `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` only "counts" code that's running; if you have a method that's doing an `await`, it won't "count" against that concurrency limit.

So, your code has ended up in a situation where it has the sync-over-async antipattern, probably because someone was trying to avoid the problem of `await` not working as expected with limited concurrency task schedulers. This sync-over-async antipattern has then caused the deadlock problem.

Now, you *could* add in more hacks by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere and continue blocking on asynchronous code, *or* you could fix it better.

A more proper fix would be to do asynchronous throttling. Toss out the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` completely; concurrency-limiting task schedulers only work with synchronous code, and your code is asynchronous. You can do asynchronous throttling using `SemaphoreSlim`, as such:

```
class TaskSchedulerTest
{
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

  public async Task RunAsync()
  {
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(id => DoWorkAsync(id));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }

  private async Task DoWorkAsync(int id)
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Starting Work {id}");
      await HttpClientGetAsync();
      Console.WriteLine($"Finished Work {id}");
    }
    finally
    {
      _mutex.Release();
    }
  }

  async Task HttpClientGetAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stephen for your answer and for laying it out to clearly. The reason that I have this problem that I'm stuck between an asynchronous API (HttpClient) and a synchronous API, and there is not much I can do about that right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are encountering a sync deadlock. You are waiting for a thread to complete that is waiting for your thread to complete. Never going to happen. If you make your DoWork method async so you can await the HttpClientGetAsync() call, and you'll avoid the deadlock.

```
using MassTransit.Util;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.Threading.Tasks.Schedulers;

namespace LimitedConcurrency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TaskSchedulerTest();
            test.Run();
        }
    }

    class TaskSchedulerTest
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2);
            var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(id => taskFactory.StartNew(() => DoWork(id)));
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private async Task DoWork(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting Work {id}");
            await HttpClientGetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished Work {id}");
        }

        async Task HttpClientGetAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d

TLDR never call .result, which I'm sure .GetResult(); was doing

Comment: Unfortunately this example doesn't work as written, `TaskFactory.StartNew` doesn't have an overload that accept  a Func<Task>.  The `tasks` list is of type `IEnumerable<Task<Task>>`.  The outer task will complete and return as soon as `DoWork` awaits.  This program will then exit after printing "Starting Work" twice and won't wait for the inner task to complete.  However if you use `Task.Unwrap()` it can.

Comment: Lol, Mr. Cleary comes in with 300k rep and delivers a more eloquent  answer than I ever could, and then I got @shf301 running my code through visual studio and nitpicking on things including warnings, while targeting the wrong sdk. Rip.